# SonarCloud error from CircleCI: Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, circleci, sonarcloud

I'm trying to get SonarCloud.io to work with CircleCI. I have a working CircleCI config (except for the SonarCloud bit) and have followed the setup instructions in SonarCloud. My CircleCI config.yml looks like this:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  sonarcloud: sonarsource/sonarcloud@1.0.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.9

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      - run: npm test            

      - run:
         name: Deploy circle-ci to Heroku Master
         command: |
           git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git +HEAD:master
      - sonarcloud/scan

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build:
          context: SonarCloud
```

I've added `sonar.projectKey` and `sonar.organization` to `sonar-project.properties` and `SONAR_TOKEN`, `SONAR_TEAM` and `SONAR_PROJECT_KEY` to the CircleCI SonarCloud context for my team.

When the pipeline runs in CircleCI, I get the following output:

```
NFO: Scanner configuration file: /tmp/cache/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.1.0.1829-linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/circleci/repo/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.1.0.1829
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.15.0-1052-aws amd64
INFO: User cache: /tmp/cache/scanner/.sonar/cache
INFO: SonarQube server 8.0.0
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.271s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/56M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: **Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.**
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Exited with code exit status 2
```

Plenty of other people seem to have had this issue, but none of the answers I've seen match my scenario or have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error it's wanting `sonar.login` to be set. You appear to be relying on `SONAR_TOKEN`, but according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/ the token should be set on `sonar.login`. Using a token for `sonar.login` negates the need for `sonar.password` to be set.

Comment: Not quite, but it pointed me in the right direction! I needed to add the SonarCloud project to the sonar-project.properties file. e.g: sonar.projectName=my-project. Appears to be working now.